# iPhone 7 screen is frozen on the shutdown screen

Tags: screen, performance

my screen is frozen on the slide to power off screen and it won't let me get out of it. I've tried holding down the home button and the lock button for a long time and it hasn't worked. I've also tried using siri and haven't gotten anywhere. I plugged in my phone as well and that didn't do anything either. I have an iPhone 7

Answer (score 0):

[For iPhone 7 and 8, you need to hold down Lock and Volume Down at the same time to reboot.](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-207128/) Older iPhones use Lock and Home button.

If you cannot restart the phone this way, [you may have to use DFU mode.](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-207264/)

(Note: These links are hosted by Verizon, but will work with any iPhone 7 or 8 on any carrier.)